# Django Model default call back not adding beyond 10

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I was hoping someone can assist with my issue in that when I used a default callback my 'account_number' field gets an Integrity Error when above 10. Without a default callback, I have no issues and it works.

My Account Model:

```
def account_number_increment():
    last_number = Account.objects.all().order_by("account_number").last()
    print("I am the last number")
    start_from = AccountSettings.account_number_startfrom
    print("I am the start from")
    acc_number = '1'
    if last_number is None:
        print("I am the initiator")
        return acc_number       
    if start_from != '' or start_from is not None:        
        while Account.objects.all().filter(account_number=start_from).exists():
            acc_number_start = int(last_number.account_number) + 1
            print("acc # from start from", str(acc_number_start))
            return str(acc_number_start)
    if last_number:    
        # last_number.refresh_from_db(fields="account_number")
        # last_number.refresh_from_db()
        while Account.objects.all().filter(account_number=last_number.account_number).exists():
            print("BEFORE addition", last_number.account_number)
            new_acc_number = int(last_number.account_number) + 1
            print("acc # new number", str(new_acc_number))
            return str(new_acc_number)   


class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                                   related_name="account_address")
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=account_number_increment, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    # account_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1def') # works with for loop in views.    
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)   
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My Account_Settings Model

```
class AccountSettings(models.Model):   
    account_number_startfrom = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='1', blank=True, null=True)   
     
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.job_number_startfrom}, {self.account_number_startfrom}, {self.invoice_number_startfrom}'
```

My views

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = AccountForm(prefix='form1', data=request.POST)
        form2 = AccountForm(prefix='form2', data=request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():       
            form1.save()
            form2.save()
            print("FORMs SAVED")
            return redirect(reverse('account:home'))
    else:      
        user1 = CustomUser.objects.create(username='userFirst')
        
        acc1 = Account.objects.create(name='IamUser40000', user=user1)
        print('this is the new 1 ----' + str(acc1.pk) + acc1.name + '--------------')         
        acc11 = Account.objects.get(pk=acc1.pk)

        acc2 = Account.objects.create(name='IamUser3000', user=user1)
        print('this is the new 2 ----' + str(acc2.pk) + acc2.name +'--------------')        
        acc22 = Account.objects.get(pk=acc2.pk)

        form1 = AccountForm(prefix='form1', instance=acc11)
        form2 = AccountForm(prefix='form2', instance=acc22)

        # for loop for non default callback
        # num = 3
        # for i in range(15):
        #     name = "IAMUSER"+str(i)
        #     account_number = str(num)
        #     Account.objects.create(name=name, account_number=account_number, user=user1)
        #     num = num + 1

        # for loop for default with call back
        for i in range(15):
            name = "IAMUSER" + str(i)
            # Account.objects.create(name=name, account_number=account_number_increment(), user=user1)
            Account.objects.create(name=name, user=user1)  

    context = {
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2,
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)
```

The error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint "account_account_account_number_a5d74cff_uniq" DETAIL:  Key
> (account_number)=(10) already exists.

Comment: Note that when you order a char column, `2` comes after `10`.

Comment: @Selcuk thank you! I'm still a beginner with Python and Django and I didn't realize the ordering of Char does that.

Comment: This is not specific to Python, Django, or to your database. That's how sorting strings works in general.